# Mockito verify invocation error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I would have a problem with the junit tests with mockito. when I try to verify a service I get the error: "Actual invocation has different arguments"

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_project")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String name;

    @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
    @Column(name = "project_language")  
    private String language;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date start_date;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date end_date;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    private Long id_user;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_content_manager")
    private User contentManager;

    @Transient
    private Long id_license;

    @OneToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_license")
    private License license;

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinTable(name = "team", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_project") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user") })
    private List<User> team;

    @OneToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_policy")
    private ProjectPolicy policy;

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinTable(name = "project2tag", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_project") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_tag") })
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
...
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json" , produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<BaseModel> edit( @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token, @RequestBody Project project, Locale locale) throws ParseException{
        if(!SecurityUtil.validateToken(token)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<BaseModel>(new BaseModel("error", MessageHandler.returnMessage("invalid_token", locale)), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        if(project.getId() == null ) {
            return new ResponseEntity<BaseModel>(new BaseModel("error", "Bad request"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        Project projecttmp = projectDao.findById(project.getId());
        if( projecttmp != null) {
            project.setContentManager(projecttmp.getContentManager());
            project.setLicense(projecttmp.getLicense());
            project.setPolicy(projecttmp.getPolicy());
            project.setTags(projecttmp.getTags());
            project.setTeam(projecttmp.getTeam());
            projectDao.editProject(project);
            return new ResponseEntity<BaseModel>(new BaseModel("ok", "ok"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<BaseModel>(new BaseModel("error", MessageHandler.returnMessage("internal_error", locale)), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

and the test with failure:

```
@Test
    public void updateProject() throws Exception{
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setId(new Long(22));

        when(projectService.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(project);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(project);

        logger.info(json);

        doNothing().when(projectService).editProject(any(Project.class));

        mockMvc.perform(put("/project/")
                .header("Authorization", TOKEN)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

        verify(projectService, times(1)).findById(eq(project.getId()));
        verify(projectService, times(1)).editProject(eq(project));
    }
```

When i can try to run the test the result is "Actual invocation has different arguments"
someone who can help me?

Comment: can you put the complete exception stactrace. Do you know exactly at which line are you getting this exception. How have you initialized projectService in your test class?

Comment: Can you put the test case class also? How are you initializing `projectService`? Is it from spring context?

Comment: @YogeshBadke yes projectService is initialized, also because all the other tests do not fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mockito.eq()` compares using `.equals()` method. You should override this method (and hashCode as well) in `Project` class, and make comparison by id. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Project project = (Project) o;

    return getId() != null ? getId().equals(project.getId()) : project.getId() == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can not test it because I do not have a pc with me, as soon as I do I will update you. Thanks again